# R clustering- silhouette with observation labels

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

I do hierarchical clustering with the `cluster` package in R. Using the `silhouette` function, I can get the silhouette plot of my cluster output for any given height (h) cut-off in the dendrogram.

```
# run hierarchical clustering
if(!require("cluster")) { install.packages("cluster");  require("cluster") } 
tmp <- matrix(c( 0,  20,  20,  20,  40,  60,  60,  60, 100, 120, 120, 120,
                 20,   0,  30,  50,  60,  80,  40,  80, 120, 100, 140, 120,
                 20,  30,   0,  40,  60,  80,  80,  80, 120, 140, 140,  80,
                 20,  50,  40,   0,  60,  80,  80,  80, 120, 140, 140, 140,
                 40,  60,  60,  60,   0,  20,  20,  20,  60,  80,  80,  80,
                 60,  80,  80,  80,  20,   0,  20,  20,  40,  60,  60,  60,
                 60,  40,  80,  80,  20,  20,   0,  20,  60,  80,  80,  80,
                 60,  80,  80,  80,  20,  20,  20,   0,  60,  80,  80,  80,
                 100, 120, 120, 120,  60,  40,  60,  60,   0,  20,  20,  20,
                 120, 100, 140, 140,  80,  60,  80,  80,  20,   0,  20,  20,
                 120, 140, 140, 140,  80,  60,  80,  80,  20,  20,   0,  20,
                 120, 120,  80, 140,  80,  60,  80,  80,  20,  20,  20,   0),
                 nr=12, dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:12], LETTERS[1:12]))

cl <- hclust(as.dist(tmp,diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE), method= 'single')
sil_cl <- silhouette(cutree(cl, h=25) ,as.dist(tmp), title=title(main = 'Good'))
plot(sil_cl)
```

This gives the figure below, which is the point that frustrates me. **How can I use the observation labels `rownames(tmp)` in the silhouette plot as opposed to the numeric indices (1 to 12) - which make no sense whatsoever to me.**

[image]

Comment: Can you make this example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by adding some sample input data. Where are the "John Malkovich" values coming from?

Comment: @MrFlick, Done, I was being lazy witht he hope that someone would know the answer without having to wrestle with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why but the `silhouette` call seems to drop the row names. You can add them back with

```
cl <- hclust(as.dist(tmp,diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE), method= 'single')
sil_cl <- silhouette(cutree(cl, h=25) ,as.dist(tmp), title=title(main = 'Good'))

rownames(sil_cl) <- rownames(tmp)

plot(sil_cl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding the argument `cex.names = par("cex.axis")` to the `plot()` function gives you the desired labels:

```
cl <- hclust(as.dist(tmp,diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE), method= 'single')
sil_cl <- silhouette(cutree(cl, h=25) ,as.dist(tmp), title=title(main = 'Good'))


plot(sil_cl, cex.names = par("cex.axis"))
```